# R Easy and compact way to write this in a single line?

Tags: r, vectorization

Imagine I have a dataframe called PAD.
And I want to add new columns.
I need to write many lines like this, (they do rowwise calculations).

```
 PAD[,"MV1"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,1:3], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV2"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,4:6], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV3"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,7:9], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV4"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,10:12], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV5"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,13:15], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV6"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,16:18], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV7"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,19:21], na.rm=TRUE)
 PAD[,"MV8"] <- rowMeans(PAD[,22:24], na.rm=TRUE)
```

or something with my own function

```
 PAD[,"VV1"] <- apply(PAD[,1:3], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV2"] <- apply(PAD[,4:6], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV3"] <- apply(PAD[,7:9], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV4"] <- apply(PAD[,10:12], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV5"] <- apply(PAD[,13:15], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV6"] <- apply(PAD[,16:18], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV7"] <- apply(PAD[,19:21], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
 PAD[,"VV8"] <- apply(PAD[,22:24], 1, function(x) min(x), na.rm=TRUE))
```

I know there exist ways to write it all in a single line (or two :) ).
Something like a for loop but avoiding the loop, maybe we could call it, vectorized version.

How can I do it?
Maybe something starting with paste0(.....)  on both sides of the assignement?
, or maybe creating a function and passing a vector, but I'm a little bit confused. I don't know if I have to use parse() or eval() or just generate sequences.

As you can see I'll take every N1 (here 3) columns, to calculate and assign it to N2 new ones (here 8).

And another question, 
is it better to assign it to ?

```
 c(PAD[,"VV1"], PAD[,"VV2"], PAD[,"VV3"], ...)
```

or to ?

```
 PAD[,"VV1","VV2","VV3"....]
```

Comment: I don't know what solution to vote, both solutions were provided at the same time and are good.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i in 1:8) {
  varname = paste('MV',i,sep='')
  PAD[,varname] <- rowMeans(PAD[, (3*n-2):(3*n)], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Yes you can do a two-liner with *apply, it is less legible though.

Comment: What about doing it without a for loop, using common vectorized R ways, such apply, do.call, 1:8 ...?

Comment: @skan, `apply()` is not considered "vectorized".  It is also a loop

Comment: OK, but at list is not so explicit.

Comment: And it's shorter like this:  for (i in 1:8) {
  PAD[, paste0('MV',i)] <- rowMeans(PAD[, (3*i-2):(3*i)], na.rm=TRUE)
}

Answer (score 1):

It's two lines:

```
cols <- split(1:24, rep(1:8, each = 3))
for (i in 1:8) PAD[[paste0("MV", i)]] <- rowMeans(PAD[, cols[[i]]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use avoid using the `for` loop, you can do this.

```
cols <- split(1:24, rep(1:8, each = 3))
tmp <- lapply(1:8, function(x) rowMeans(PAD[, cols[[x]]], na.rm = TRUE))
names(tmp) <- paste0("MV", 1:8)
PAD <- cbind(PAD, do.call(cbind, tmp))
```

Comment: What about doing it without a for loop, using common vectorized R ways, such apply, do.call, 1:8 ...?

Comment: I edited my answer to use lapply, and do.call as you requested